# Condition with enum always evaluating to true

Tags: c++, enums

Ok I am sure there has to be something stupid here. I haven't really used an enum so maybe I am just doing something incorrect. I am creating a red-black tree implementation and I am using an enum inside of class Node to for if it is a red or black node. I've stepped through the code and when I reach this statement for the given node I am trying to insert, it should not execute the loop as the parent's color is black not red! For some reason this evaluates to true and I am not sure why... Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you! :)

```
while(x->m_parent->m_color == (Node::Color::ST_Red)) ;
```

This is part of my Node class just in case.

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node()
    {
        m_data = 0 ;    
        m_color = Node::Color::ST_Red ; 
    }

    enum Color
    {
        ST_Red,
        ST_Black
    };

private:
    int m_data ;    
    Color m_color ; 
    Node* m_parent; 

};
```

Comment: `Color::ST_Red` is not valid. You'd need an `enum class` for that. And inside `Node`, `Node::` shouldn't be used.

Comment: Where's your loop body? Are you sure you actually move to the next node?

Comment: You have `;` at the end of `while` in your real code also?

Comment: The code you've shown is an infinite loop. Get rid of the `;` after the `while`.

Comment: I did not include the body of the loop because I did not think it would be needed. When I step through the code I can see that it enters the loop and it is comparing the correct node.

Comment: Even though your way of using enum's as namespaces appears to be weird, it still works just as expected: http://ideone.com/LffkyZ

Comment: I found out what it was. It was exactly as Pete said, there was a semicolon entered into the code that I did not notice until he did. A stupid mistake I overlooked! Thank you for helping me everyone!